# Flex: Display rich text in AdvancedDataGrid column?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, advanceddatagrid, richtext

I have some rich text created using the flex (flash builder 4) rich text input control.  I want to display at least some of it in a column of an AdvancedDataGrid control.

Is this possible / how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create an itemRenderer which extends the [MXDataGridItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/MXDataGridItemRenderer.html) class and put a RichText control inside the itemRenderer to display the text.

Be sure to set your new itemRenderer as the itemRenderer for the AdvancedDataGrid column you want to display these values in.

Answer (score 0):

Use [item renderers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html)?  But be warned as using RichText means possibly more parsing and performance issues (depending on your situation).